# I can't figure out why it is not letting me click on the hyperlinks at the left ordered list

Tags: html, web, hyperlink

I am making a project for my school and we are learning about HTML and I have to make a page about websites I use and don't use. While I was making the website I saw that I couldn't click on links on the left ordered list. Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cool Page</title>
    <style>
      p { color:red;}
      body {

        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
        background-size: 400% 400%;
        animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      @keyframes gradient {
        0% {
          background-position: 0% 50%;
        }
        50% {
          background-position: 100% 50%;
        }
        100% {
          background-position: 0% 50%;
        }


      }
      #main-title  { 
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 3px -2px black;
        font-size: 50px;  
        text-align:center;
      } 
      #one {
        color: paleturquoise;text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        font-size: 35px; 
        text-align:left;
      }
      #two {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        font-size: 35px; 
        text-align:right;
      } 
      #ol-one {
        text-align:left;
        list-style-position: inside;
      }
      #ol-two {
        text-align: right;
        list-style-position: inside;
      }
      #li-one {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        font-size: 25px; 
        text-align:left;
      }
      #li-two {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        font-size: 25px; 
        text-align:right;
      }
      #litext-one {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        font-size: 18px; 
        text-align:left; 
      }
      #litext-two {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        font-size: 18px; 
        text-align:right; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="position:relative; left:-50px; top:1px;">
      <h1 id="main-title">
        Websites I Use and Used To Use
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative; left:1px; top:2px;">
      <h2 id="one">
        Websites I use
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative; right:20px; top:-66px;">
      <h2 id="two">
        Websites I don't use
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative; left:1px; top:-70px;">
      <ol id="ol-one">
        <li id="li-one">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-one">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
        <li id="li-one">
          <a href="https://soraapp.com">
            Sora
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-one">
          I use Sora to read books almost everyday.
        </div>
        <li id="li-one">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-one">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
      </ol>  
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative; left:1px; top:-315px;">
      <ol id="ol-two">
        <li id="li-two">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-two">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
        <li id="li-two">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-two">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
        <li id="li-two">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-two">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
      </ol>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just paste it in a HTML editor and try to figure out why I can't click on hyperlinks on the left ordered list, it would help a lot.

I expected the hyperlinks on the left ordered list to be clickable, for some reason they aren't but when I move them up with `<div style="position:relative; left:1px; top:-70px;">` over the "Websites I use" heading, it does let me click on it, please figure out how to be able to click on the links on the left ordered list while it's under the heading "Websites I use". Thank you. (Note: I am fairly new to HTML)

Answer (score 0):

The reason links are not clickable is you are overlapping one div over another by using relative positioning. You can use flex box to layout your page. Something like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cool Page</title>
    <style>
      p { color:red;}
      body {

        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
        background-size: 400% 400%;
        animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      @keyframes gradient {
        0% {
          background-position: 0% 50%;
        }
        50% {
          background-position: 100% 50%;
        }
        100% {
          background-position: 0% 50%;
        }


      }
      #main-title  { 
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 3px -2px black;
        font-size: 50px;  
        text-align:center;
      } 
      #one {
        color: paleturquoise;text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        font-size: 35px;
      }
      #two {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        font-size: 35px; 
      } 
            
      #ol-one {
        list-style-position: inside;
      }
      #ol-two {
        list-style-position: inside;
      }
      #li-one {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        font-size: 25px; 
      }
      #li-two {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        font-size: 25px; 
      }
      #litext-one {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        font-size: 18px; 
      }
      #litext-two {
        color: paleturquoise;
        text-shadow: 2px -1px black; 
        font-size: 18px; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 id="main-title">
        Websites I Use and Used To Use
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
          <h2 id="one">
        Websites I use
      </h2>
      <h2 id="two">
        Websites I don't use
      </h2>
    </div>
        
        <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        
        
    <div style="left-container">
      <ol id="ol-one">
        <li id="li-one">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-one">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
        <li id="li-one">
          <a href="https://soraapp.com">
            Sora
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-one">
          I use Sora to read books almost everyday.
        </div>
        <li id="li-one">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-one">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
      </ol>  
    </div>
        
        <div style="right-container">
      <ol id="ol-two">
        <li id="li-two">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-two">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
        <li id="li-two">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-two">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
        <li id="li-two">
          <a href="https://code.org">
            Code.org
          </a>
        </li>
        <div id="litext-two">
          Before I came to this school I knew about this website but I had 
          <br>only used it once, now I use it almost everyday for HTML coding.
        </div>
      </ol>  
    </div>
        
        </div>
        
    
  </body>
</html>
```

You can read more about Flexbox here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me. I am very grateful for you commenting.